# Multi-cursor editing in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

Previously, to enable multi-cursor editing in Jupyter Notebook, I used the a custom JS snippet:

```
require(["codemirror/keymap/sublime", "notebook/js/cell", "base/js/namespace"],
    function(sublime_keymap, cell, IPython) {
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'sublime';
        var cells = IPython.notebook.get_cells();
        for(var cl=0; cl< cells.length ; cl++){
            cells[cl].code_mirror.setOption('keyMap', 'sublime');
        }
    }
);
```

I thought I would be able to accomplish the same thing under `Settings->Text Editor Keymap->Sublime`, but this doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the cell editor of Jupyter Lab is not yet supported. See the discussion in these issues:

- [#3992](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3992) Support keymaps in notebook cells
- [#1362](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1362) Support Vim Editing Mode in Cells

Answer (score 10):

It's possible now: 'ctrl + mouse click'

Comment: Also try these two. Alt+click and Ctrl+Alt+click

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning, I have found sometime you must go to settings and change the "code jump" setting to use "control" instead of the default "alt" key (on macOS only tested) to enable multiline select to work. It's an annoying issue but the change works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt and you just hold your left mouse button and drag your mouse downwards to put multiple cursors