# JupyterLab keyboard shortcut to duplicate cursor

Tags: jupyter-lab

I can hold alt then click and drag in a line to create a line of cursors. However, I'd rather do this with a keyboard shortcut (e.g. alt + up creates a new cursor on the line above the current one). I don't see anything about cursor duplication in the Keyboard Shortcuts file or the command palette - does this mean there is no way to set up a shortcut for this? If not, what command do I need to bind to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Does `Ctrl+Alt+Click` work? Just a quick tip, I do not think simply using the keyboard is possible to do what you want to achieve.

- [#3992](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3992) Support keymaps in notebook cells
- [#1362](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1362) Support Vim Editing Mode in Cells

Relevant sources:

- [Multi-cursor editing in Jupyter Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988636/multi-cursor-editing-in-jupyter-lab)